# RestKit - RkObjectManager callback methods not triggered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm new to iOS development. I'd like to use RestKit to access a web service and map the data to my custom objects.

I am certain that the search method is being reached. However, neither of the callback methods (didLoadObjects or didFailWithError) is being triggered. My code is below.  Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** I tried doing the same thing with a simple RKClient request, and those callback methods were not triggered either. I also implemented the "Observing Request Progress" methods, and those methods were not triggered either. Am I not assigning the delegate correctly?

**EDIT 2:** It looks like maybe the request is getting stuck in the queue. If I force it to send asynchronously, then the methods "requestWillPrepareForSend" and "requestDidStartLoad" are triggered. No other methods are triggered.

```
- (void)search{

NSString *baseURL = @"sws.acpl.lib.in.us:8080/symws/rest/";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];

RKObjectManager *manager=[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:url];

RKObjectMapping *availabilityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TitleAvailabilityInfo class]];

[availabilityMapping mapAttributes:@"totalAvailableCopies", @"holdable", nil];

RKObjectMapping *titleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SearchResultsTitle class]];
[titleMapping mapAttributes:@"titleID",@"title",@"author",@"materialType",@"yearOfPublication",@"ISBN",@"callNumber", nil];
[titleMapping mapKeyPath:@"TitleAvailabilityInfo" toRelationship:@"titleAvailabilityInfo" withMapping:availabilityMapping];

RKObjectMapping *searchResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SearchCatalogResponse class]];
[searchResponseMapping mapAttributes:@"queryID",@"totalHits",@"firstHitDisplayed",@"lastHitDisplayed", nil];
[searchResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"HitlistTitleInfo" toRelationship:@"results" withMapping:titleMapping];



[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:searchResponseMapping    forKeyPath:@"SearchCatalogResponse"];

[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"standard/searchCatalog" delegate:self];

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {

NSLog(@"loaded");
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
NSLog(@"failed");
}
```

Comment: Are <RKRequestDelegate, RKObjectLoaderDelegate> added to your interface?  Sounds like rkrequestdelegate is but not rkobjectloaderdelegate

Comment: Also, put this in your app delegate "didFinishLaucnhingWithOptions" method to enable rest kit logging in console.      RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the URL. I left off "http://" at the beginning. Thanks for your help.